# std::vector<> assignment operation not working; need 'clear' operation first

Tags: c++, std, stdvector

I am confused by what I thought should be a very simple operation. I call a method that creates a std::vector and returns it. Then I set an existing std::vector to that result, expecting the = operator to work. The code looks like this:

```
std::vector<BTLECharDecl> charDeclList;

charDeclList.clear();

// get the services on the agent
// It loads the discovered services into the class variable 'serviceList'
if((result = discoverServices()) != rc_SUCCESS)
{
    std::cout <<  "Discovering service failed. Function returned message "
              <<  eResultCode2str(result) << "(" << hex << result << dec << ")" << endl;
    return result;
}

if(serviceList.size() > 0)
{
    for(uint16 i = 0; i < serviceList.size(); i++)
    {
        // Get chararcteristic Declaration List as Objects for each service
        startHandle = serviceList.at(i).getServiceData().startHandle;
        endHandle = serviceList.at(i).getServiceData().endHandle;

        if(startHandle < endHandle)
        {
            // !! WHY DO I NEED THIS clear()?? !!
            charDeclList.clear();
            charDeclList = discoverCharDecl(serviceList.at(i).getServiceData().startHandle, endHandle);
        }
```

If I do not invoke the charDeclList.clear() method before the call to the method that returns this type of object, I will get leftover garbage from previous loops. Not always, but sometimes. I would have expected the assignment operator to completely replace whatever was there with that which is returned by the called method. What is wrong with my thinking? (Invoking the clear() solves the problem but it is unsettling.) Working with MS Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: Sounds like something in the `discoverCharDecl(serviceList.at(i).getServiceData().startHandle` (of which you did not post any code) is pointing at your vector's contents. Or you are incorrectly determining the result of the assignment.  To get better help post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Actually I stepped through the method and everything is fine. The two parameters passed in are just integers. The std::vector has what it should have just before the 'return' is called at the end of the method. Upon invoking the return, the result has additional stuff that was not in the object at the time of the return.

Comment: You will need to post a MCVE; another possibility is that your program causes UB before getting to this point.

Comment: it's not std::vector's fault, but some logical error on your part. Please do post more code, otherwise we can't be specific. Seems like you reference the contents of your vector and do something with it. Or it may be heap corruption via undefined behavior. In any case - need more code :)